# postgresql dump on ubuntu for user postgres

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pg-dump

I'm logged into remote using ssh

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

now I switch to postgres account using  `sudo su - postgres` command and it send me to `postgres@ubuntu:~$`

now here I'm able to take dump using `pg_dump` command.

e.g.  `postgres@ubuntu:~$ pg_dump db_name > mydbdump.sql`

so far looks good. but from here I want to copy this dump file to my local machine or even to my origin/default ubuntu user on remote(ubuntu@ubuntu:~$). so that from there I can `scp`.

how do I copy these dump sql files from postgres acccount to ubuntu on remote?

Comment: After you've created a dump run `pwd` to determine current directory. It will return something like `/var/lib/postgresql`. Then return back to your `ubuntu` user: `exit`. And copy dump to your user's home directory: `cp /var/lib/postgresql/mydbdump.sql ~/mydbdump.sql`. After that you'll be able to copy it to your local machine using `scp`

Comment: You need to find out, which directory your dump is written to (```pwd```). Then you just copy it with your normal ubuntu user to your home and use scp: ```sudo cp /path/to/mydbdump.sql /home/ubuntu/```. Now you can use scp: ```scp ubuntu@whateveraddress.com:/home/ubuntu/mydbdump.sql .``` and you are done. Futhermore this question rather belongs to http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ubuntu, default directory would be `/var/lib/postgresql`

so you can directly `scp` from remote to local.

On your local machine run this command

```
user@user:~$ scp ubuntu@someaddress.com:/var/lib/postgresql/mydbdump.sql /path/to/local/dir
```